# WPF DataGrid cell converter checking

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, datagridcell

I currently have this XAML that successfully enables/disables a row

```
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

However, I know need it so it doesnt disable the entire row, but only 2 cells. I am guessing its going to be something like...

```
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

But how do I only check the cells I want to disable?

Thanks

Comment: Use StyleSelector... follow this link, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.styleselector.aspx

Comment: Looking at the link, I am unsure that we can still use the Converter class?

Comment: You dont want to use Converter, Write the logic in the Selector and assign the Style that required.

Comment: Ok, so do I assign the style to the specific cells I want? with n triggers?

Comment: Yes. You can use like this..

Comment: Will answer later, but got it to work like this

As well as Sankarann answer of using a a StyleSelector, if you have a converter then you can do this 
<DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
   <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
  </DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>

Will answer properly when SO will let me